# Require library inside mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to require a library in mongo shell? I need to run some code (update my documents) and for that I need a specific library. In example:

```
require("library")
...Some code
MyTable.update()
```

I know that I could run inside node.js, so I am looking for the mongo shell solution.

Comment: Mongo Shell has very specific purpose and I'll not suggest pushing it's boundaries. If you really need customization, choose appropriate tool.

Comment: Do you have any example of such a tool?:)

Comment: I mean, language such as nodejs or another programming language.

Comment: @Saleem That is not the question. I know I could use node.js :)

Comment: You can load javascript files with [load](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/)

Comment: @Schore Yes but I cant do "var thelib=require("thelib")" then in the loaded file:/